# Which value of num when initialized would give this nested loop a "true" output?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

Had this question on an exam and am pretty sure there's some sort of trick to it.

"Suppose num was initialized to a certain value prior to this loop. Which value of num would give a "true" output?"

```
int result = 0; 
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
     if (i % 3 == 1)
     result += i;

     if result == num 
          cout << "True" << endl;
     else
          cout << "False" << endl;
```

a) 4

b) 5

c) 6

d) 7

Am a newbie programmer. Can anyone interpret what's going on?

Comment: what prevents you from putting a `int num = ??` in front of this code, run it and see what is the output? you have 4 options given, simply try them out

Comment: Or when you're on an exam, you can 'run' it in your head. *"what's going on"* What specific part of the code is unclear?

Comment: my interpretation of what is going on is that you didnt do any research before posting here ;)

Comment: The indentation is very misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the problem write down a list of integer numbers that give the remainder equal to 1.

```
1, 4, 7, ...
```

and then calculate their sums

```
1, 5, 12, ...
```

Thus the correct answer is `num` is erqual to `5` because it is the only number in the list of the suggested answers ( 4, 5, 6, 7 ) that also is present in the list of the sums.

Pay attention to the correct writing of the if statement.

There must be

```
if ( result == num )
```

instead of

```
if result == num
```